# R Studio: Certain packages install, while others will not install

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, install.packages

I can load many packages (cluster for example) in my R Studio System library, but I can’t load other packages, dplyr for example, even though it appears in the System Library.  For example when I try to load dplyr, I get this error message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
 there is no package called ‘DBI’
```

But then when I’ve tried to load the DBI package, I get this error message:

```
'\\s10file\user$\ben.k\My Documents\R\win-library\3.4'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages : 
running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.4revised/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4revised\library" "C:/Users/Ben.K/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgTzZma/downloaded_packages/DBI_0.7.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages : installation of package 
‘C:/Users/Ben.K/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgTzZma/downloaded_packages/DBI_0.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have also tried the following:

- Setting install.packages dependencies = TRUE
- Having IT change my Administrator rights for R
- Editing the System Environment variables
- Opening and running R Studio as an Adminstrator
- Changing the file path for install.packages
- Probably a few other things I forgot to document

I've had a similar issue with ggplot2 and fpc as well. I’m no R expert, any assistance is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: IT ended up reinstalling R and R Studio and everything works as it should now.